# implementing QR code scanning on a unity HoloLens2 app

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, qr-code, hololens

I am trying to implement QR code scanning for my Hololens2 AR app on unity and I can't seem to figure it out. There is Microsoft documentation here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/platform-capabilities-and-apis/qr-code-tracking), but this documentation does not show how to implement using C# scripts (which is what would be ideal). It points to a confusing example project which does not run on my end. I have looked around and can not seem to find any helpful guides for implementing this.

If anyone has done this before or knows how to, could you help out?

Comment: Which confusing example project? [This one?](https://github.com/chgatla-microsoft/QRTracking/tree/master/SampleQRCodes). Please explain what happens when you try to open it in a way that is more descriptive than "does not run". Does the editor load but it provides you with compiler errors? Does the editor refuse to load and gives you an error message? Does it silently crash? Does it format your hard drive? There is no way for us to know.

Comment: Yes, that is the project. When I do attempt to run the project I get a COMException error in unity [System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () (at <fb001e01371b4adca20013e0ac763896>:0]. This may be because I need to install the windows mixed reality portal app (however this is not stated in the documentation). The project has a couple of scripts in it that do the Qr tracking, but I was wondering if there was another way to implement QR scanning (in the microsoft documentation, they give a c++ file that is a QR scanner and I would essentially replicate that in C#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a brand new MixedReality project, copy the scripts and prefabs from that project, add a GameObject to your scene (e.g. QRCodeManager) and attach `QRCodeManager.cs` and `QRCodeHandler.cs` to it. You can tick "Auto Start QR Tracking" in `QRCodesManager` (in Unity Editor) in order to start scanning for QRCodes by default. `QRCodesVisualizer.cs` deals with QRCode detection events (HandleEvents()). If you are using the scripts as they are, as soon as a QRCode is detected you will have a visual confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still waiting... I have installed the same project and Deploy it in Hololens 2. It worked fine. Here is what I have done.
If you have not already, create a github account and Clone the project (SampleQRCodes). You can open it from Unity Hub or just go to the directory, then Assets > Scenes and open [QRCodesSample.unty]. Its all set actually. Nothing to do. Change the Platform from [PC, Mac & Linux Standalone] to [Universal Windows Platform], then [Switch platform]. I assume that you know how to Deploy it in Hololens 2. If not please tell. Its simple. You need VS 2019 (professional).  Community won't work.

Comment: How do you know VS 2019 Community won't work? I have been wondering why everyone seems to think the project "just works" out of the box yet it crashes for me. If you are right and Community edition doesn't work, why the hell doesn't Microsoft state that? I double checked the page and the Unity github project and no where does it state you need VS Pro for it to work.

Comment: I am not a regular user of VS 2019. Only used for this purpose. For me I have tried with community but it did not work. But worked with pro. So thought I should mention it.